# Ubuntu 12.04 can't log into graphical user interface

Tags: 12.04, drivers

Somehow when I update packages, I lost the graphics driver installed in my system, and it now only logs me into tty1. when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> the cursor blinks at the top of my screen and nothing happens. Same happens when I use this command

```
    sudo service lightdm restart
```

I tried:

```
    sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current

    sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

But no changes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is a problem of the graphics driver or could it be also a defect in the Desktop Environment (Unity for standard)? Maybe you could try reinstalling them, or another one alongside it, such as xfce, lxde, cinnamon, gnome, etc...